# neo4j 2.0 having trouble starting

Tags: java, neo4j

I have my DB_Path

```
String DB_PATH = "path/to/data/graph.db"
```

then I am running

```
GraphDatabaseService graphDb = new EmbeddedGraphDatabase(DB_PATH)
```

In which I am met with (full exception)

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.XaDataSourceManager@10f102d3' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:319)
at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.<init>(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:100)
at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory$1.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:92)
at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase(GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:197)
at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:69)
at TestConnect.main(TestConnect.java:26)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.XaDataSourceManager@10f102d3' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:504)
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:115)
at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:296)
... 10 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreXaDataSource@178aab40' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:504)
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:115)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.XaDataSourceManager.start(XaDataSourceManager.java:126)
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:498)
... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/nio/channels/SeekableByteChannel
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaLogicalLog.doInternalRecovery(XaLogicalLog.java:765)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaLogicalLog.open(XaLogicalLog.java:205)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaLogicalLog.open(XaLogicalLog.java:160)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaContainer.openLogicalLog(XaContainer.java:64)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreXaDataSource.start(NeoStoreXaDataSource.java:304)
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:498)
... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.nio.channels.SeekableByteChannel
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
... 21 more
```

However if I run a clearDB before i.e.

```
try
{
   FileUtils.deleteRecursively(new File(DB_PATH));
}
catch ( IOException e )
{
   throw new RuntimeException( e );
}
```

Anyone have any more thought into this?  Thanks!

Comment: Is there really a trailing `/` in your path? You prolly meant `"path/to/data/graph.db"`

Comment: Could you post the attached cause exception?

Comment: updated.  Full exception.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out it was a versioning problem.  You need to run this in Java 7